# tabbar-local-mode vs semantic-stickyfunc-mode

Tags: tabbar, semantic

When `semantic-stickyfunc-mode` is activated, the tabbar tabs are not visible.

I would like to write a function that show the tabs 2 seconds and then goes to `semantic-stickyfunc-mode`.

I tried with this:

```el
     (defun timer-local-tabbar-show()
        (if (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
            (progn
              (tabbar-local-mode -1)
              (run-with-timer 2 nil (lambda () (tabbar-local-mode 1))))))
      (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'timer-local-tabbar-show)
```

The tabs are shown, and then disappear (good ;-), but `semantic-stickyFunc-mode` doesn't work (while `semantic-stickyFunc-mode` variable is 1)

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

```el
(defvar my-header-line-format nil)
  (defun timer-local-tabbar-show()
    (if (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
        (progn
          (setq my-header-line-format header-line-format)
          (tabbar-local-mode -1)
          (run-with-timer 1.5 nil
                          (lambda ()
                            (tabbar-local-mode 1)
                            (setq header-line-format my-header-line-format)
                            (redisplay)
                            )))))
  (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'timer-local-tabbar-show)
```

This version works better (thanks `lawlist`) but there are somme persistent random problems.

Comment: How about storing the value for `header-line-format` in a separate variable such as `(defvar my-header-line-format nil)` and then `(setq my-header-line-format header-line-format)` immediately **before** permitting `tabbar-mode` to take control, and then restore the value immediately **after** exiting `tabbar-mode`:  `(setq header-line-format my-header-line-format)`?  You may need to trigger a `(redisplay)` at the very end to get the screen to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edit my question with your suggestions.